# Conditional random number generator python numpy

Tags: python, numpy, random, conditional-statements, generator

I want to create a random number generator but with condition.

code is like below;

```
s_weights = []
num = 3
limit = 50000
np.random.seed(101)

for x in range(limit):
    weights = np.random.random(num)
    weights /= np.sum(weights)
    s_weights.append(weights)
```

it returns me 50.000 lists of numpy array of 3 weights (3,) like below

```
0.429134083359603413e-01 5.115615408184341906e-01 2.552505084560561729e-02
```

I want to limit first weight with rule of >=0.60

first weight should change between 0.60 - 1.00 and other two should change between 0.00 - 1.00

how can I modify the code?

thanks in advance

Comment: these 3 weights sum must be equal to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale the first weight and then generate the other weights to respect
the restriction of summing to 1.
The updated code is below:

```
import numpy as np
s_weights = []
num = 3
limit = 50000
np.random.seed(101)
offset = 0.6

for x in range(limit):
    # By default all the weights go from 0 to 1
    weights = np.random.random(num)
    # shift and scale the first one to go from 0.6 to 1
    # in the case offset is 0.6 then it is x*0.4 + 0.6, which for 0 in 0 to 1 always falls in 0.6 to 1
    weights[0] = weights[0]*(1-offset) + offset 
    # Scales the second weight respecting that the sum must be 1
    second_max = 1-weights[0]
    weights[1] = weights[1]*second_max
    # third component should be equal to the value we need to complete 1
    weights[2] = 1-weights[0]-weights[1]
    s_weights.append(weights)
print(weights)
print(sum(weights))
```

an example output of a set of weights their sum is below

```
[0.84739308 0.11863514 0.03397177]
1.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I forgot to say all weights sum must be equal to 1, they are like percentage.

Comment: I edited the answer to accommodate the restriction of the numbers summing to 1